# SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to return the last inserted ID

Tags: excel, vba, t-sql, adodb, scope-identity

There are a few answers about this problem, but my question is about the particular code I have.

I'm trying to get the last inserted ID of this query executing on VBA code.

```vb
Public Function Execute(cQry As excfw_dbQuery) As ADODB.Recordset    

    If pConn.State = 0 Then
        OpenConnection
    End If

    qry = "INSERT INTO [some really long query, which actually works]; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open qry, pConn 'also tried with adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    'some error handling code which is not related to the issue 

    Set rs = rs.NextRecordset() 'also tried without moving onto the next recordset
    pInsertedId = rs.Fields(0).Value

    Set Execute = rs 'this is just to pass the query result for SELECT queries 

End Function
```

This should save the last inserted ID on the pInsertedId variable, but instead I get 0 each time I insert a row. The weird thing is, when I copy and paste the same code into the SSMS, it works.

I might just get away with inserting some unique data to some unused column of the database and querying through that.

--UPDATE--

I've just noticed that when running a SELECT query, rs object remains open until it goes out of scope. Here is a screenshot of the watch section:

[image: select statement]

on an insert statement instead, it gets closed as soon as the query gets executed:

[image: insert statement]

Comment: Debugging tip: Try replacing `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` with `select 42;` and making sure that works.

Comment: Just tried that, it returns 0. In fact, while trying that I've noticed that while running a `SELECT` query, rs object remains open until it goes out of scope. When I run the `INSERT`query, it immediately gets closed after executing the first query.

Comment: Try running the sql statement directly in SSMS. If you get back the correct value, you know for sure the problem is with the VBA side (which is the most likely bet even before that test).

Comment: @ZoharPeled I've already did that. That was, in fact, the first thing I've tried. Question states this detail.

Comment: @SercioSoydanov sorry, missed that somehow.

Comment: No sweat hombre ;-)

Comment: Have you looked into adding an [`output` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to the `insert` statement to save the identity value? You can `select` the results later to return them as a recordset.

Comment: @HABO No, I'll look into it, thanks. But if you can add that as an answer, along with a working example, I can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly save the results of the `insert` statement by using an [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause and return the results with a `select`:

```
qry =
  "declare @Ids as ( Id Int );" +
  "insert into MyTable ( Name ) " + ' Assuming   Id   is an identity column.
     "output Inserted.Id into @Ids " + 
     "values ( @Name );" +
  "select Id from @Ids;"
```

From the documentation for `output`:

> INSERTED Is a column prefix that specifies the value added by the
>   insert or update operation. Columns prefixed with INSERTED reflect the
>   value after the UPDATE, INSERT, or MERGE statement is completed but
>   before triggers are executed.

You can use an `output` clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows. `Output` can be used with `insert`, `update`, `delete` and `merge` and provides access to both *before* and *after* values in the case of `update`. A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Comment: Great, I'll try it right away. For the cleanliness sake, can you update with a fully working example of a complete insert statement, for a very simple sample table composed of two columns, such as id and name?

Comment: @SercioSoydanov As requested. I've also assumed that it is a parameterized query with `@Name` passed in. Your query may vary.

Comment: I've tried it. If a table has triggers attached to it you still have to advance through recordsets to reach the result of the desired query, as described in my answer. But this info was so valuable for me and your answer is really useful, so I've accepted your answer.

Comment: Only thing that would be great to have, if you be so kind, is if you can emphasize this In your answer, so others can benefit from it too, in case they skip reading my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SercioSoydanov Okay, I'll bite. Triggers don't usually return recordsets as results, they just quietly validate, update or log data in the background. What are your triggers doing that produces output? What is supposed to be using the data, or are they just "leaking" data that was handy for debugging?

Comment: This was surprising for me too, because the default behavior should be exactly as you described. But I cannot think anything else to cause this behavior. I have to move forward four times with NextRecordset to reach to the newly inserted id. And we have 3 triggers for insert statements on this table. If this is a coincidence, it is a weird one. This is definitely worth investigating further. The problem is solved, but I'll be recreating this table structure IN my local dev server sometime later and go down to the nuts and bolts of it, so we can figure out what is really happening.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the table that I'm trying to insert to has multiple triggers attached to it. So, the query which includes the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); is actually 4th query. I had to move 4 queries forward in order to get the correct scope. How I pulled that off programatically is as follows. Not very clean (and possibly not the best way to do it), but does the job for me.

I basically go ahead to next recordset until there is none left, which I detect by checking the error number 91 (Object variable or with block variable not set)

```vba
Public Function Execute(cQry As excfw_dbQuery) As ADODB.Recordset    

    If pConn.State = 0 Then
        OpenConnection
    End If

    qry = "INSERT INTO [some really long query, which actually works]; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open cQry.Query, pConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    'some error handling code which is not related to the issue 

    On Error Resume Next
    'begin loop
    Do
        'go to next recordset
        Set rs = rs.NextRecordset()

        'if we're getting error n. 91, it means 
        'recordsets are exhausted, hence we're getting
        'out of the loop 
        If Err.Number = 91 Then
            Err.Clear
            Exit Do
        End If

        'if we are not out of recordsets, check the 
        'result of the query. If it is bigger then zero, 
        'it means we hit the jackpot. 
        If rs.Fields(0).Value > 0 Then
            pInsertedId = rs.Fields(0).Value
        End If
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Again, not the cleanest, nor the most correct way to do it, but did the trick. I'm open for any improvements or suggestions.